# Select text and copy from label xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, copy, label

I have for some days been reading on different forums about the issue of selecting a text and copying the text natively from a label in xamarin forms and it seems to be no straightforward way of implementing this.

My problem is that I need to present a large amount of data from a book in a label and the user should be able to select and copy a chunk of text from the label.
I moved on to present the data in an Editor component instead but then the user can edit the text in the Editor. Making the Editor component read-only doesn't solve the problem either.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, if you haven't read [mcve] yet, please do so and edit your question. What i miss in particular is - the code/xaml what you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: here is discussion regarding copying label text [link of label text copying](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/29775/selecting-label-text-for-copy-and-paste)

Comment: Thanks but i have already looked through that forum page before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently faced the same business requirement. An `Editor` with `Renderers` customization on each platform was the solution for me.

In short, `Android renderer` leverages `CustomSelectionActionModeCallback` and `CustomInsertionActionModeCallback` properties of `EditText` to customize context menu for text selection and insertion, while `iOS renderer` is pretty straight-forward and sets `Selectable` and `Editable` properties of `UITextView`.

Check out my [post](https://medium.com/@anna.domashych/selectable-read-only-multiline-text-field-in-xamarin-forms-69d09276d580) with full code for `Xamarin.Forms`. You can also read posts on [native Android](https://medium.com/@anna.domashych/selectable-read-only-multiline-text-field-on-android-169c27c55408) and [native iOS](https://medium.com/@anna.domashych/selectable-read-only-multiline-text-field-on-ios-7a5f5a44bd9) for more details.

Comment: Great! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same requirement and I implemented [CustomLabelRenderer](https://github.com/chetanrawat04/CustomLabelRenderer) for Android and iOS platform.