# Xamarin.IOS Prevent scrolling to bottom on select

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

(The render logic comes from the following Answer in this SO post: [Select text and copy from label xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48165549/select-text-and-copy-from-label-xamarin-forms?rq=1))

I am having an issue where a read only Editor that I have is exhibiting strange behavior in iOS. When I go to highlight an item, it will scroll first to the bottom, and then back to the middle the moment I select a text to highlight. However, after it does that for the first time, it will then no longer do so again (which is good). However, it always does that once for the first time when you enter the detail view. This all began since we had a bug where users could not select text to copy and paste, that part is fixed, but now iOS is displaying this issue

Here is the custom Editor class:

```
public partial class BorderlessReadOnlyEditor : Editor {

    }
```

Here is the Renderer:

```
public class BorderlessReadOnlyEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null) return;

            Control.Selectable = true;
            Control.Editable = false;
            Control.ScrollEnabled = false;
            Control.TextContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
            Control.TextContainer.LineFragmentPadding = 0;
        }
    }
```

The XAML is as follows, I am rendering my view (DetailComponent) as part of my DetailPage as so:

```
<StackLayout 
                Margin="20, 0, 20, 0"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <views:DetailComponent />
                <views:DetailComponent x:Name="Details"/>
            </StackLayout>
```

Then inside the DetailView itself, the area where I am displaying the text that the user saved before hand, is as follows:

```
<ScrollView 
        x:Name="BodyScroller" 
        x:FieldModifier="Public"
        Margin="0, 0, 0, 30" 
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
        <Label 
        <customcontrols:BorderlessReadOnlyEditor 
            x:Name="BodyLabel"
            x:FieldModifier="Public"
            Text="{Binding SelectedNote.Body}"
            TextColor="Black"
            FontSize="16"
            VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
    </ScrollView>
```

If I need to also show the code behind, let me know. Really I would just love to be able to prevent any automatic scrolling behavior as much as possible. Originally it was a label, but my understanding (from what i was told) that in Xamarin it is a hard to allow UI text highlighting and copying if it is a label

Comment: Can you provide a sample with this problem as I am not able to reproduce the problem on my side? And is the problem still happen if you don't use custom renderer?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I don't have a small working example just yet, but trying a regular editor seems to make all the characters sit on top of each other

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of all the characters sit on top of each other?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I was actually able to fix it, I will add my answer once I get back to my PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was two fold

1. First, I had to remove the  that surrounded my custom editor
2. Then in the code I had to manually set up the height of the BodyLabel (the custom editor) in the DetailComponent.xaml.cs which houses the Editor as follows:

   public partial class DetailComponent : StackLayout {
           public DetailComponent() {
               InitializeComponent();

   ```
           if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
           {
               this.BodyLabel.HeightRequest = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height * 0.25;
           } else
           {
               this.BodyLabel.HeightRequest = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height * 0.33;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Where the percentages are designed to ensure scrolling as we have a standard header size at the top (so for your specific use cases you might need to modify them if this answer helps you)